# glEnableClientState was not declared in OpenGL v4.5

Tags: opengl

I am using OpenGL version 4.5.0 and getting this error:

```
error: ‘glEnableClientState’ was not declared in this scope
```

I have read that `glEnableClientState` is deprecated in this version, but I need to write code compatible with this method, as this is home assignment from class and they require us to write using this method. Is there any way could I get this working in OpenGL 4.5.0?

Including this has had no effect:

```
glutInitContextVersion (3,3);
glutInitContextProfile (GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> glutInitContextProfile (GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
> ```

That's the opposite of what you need to do. If you need compatibility OpenGL features, then you have to use `GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE`.

However:

> error: ‘glEnableClientState’ was not declared in this scope

That suggests that the [OpenGL loading library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) you're using doesn't even *declare* this function. Which means you need to move to one that can expose compatibility profile OpenGL functions.

Comment: I have `glew1.6` and `glew2` installed. How can I import a previous version in C++? `#include <GL/glew.h>` seems to be importing `glew2`.

Comment: @Mario: Both of them should have that function, so it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: The line `#include <GL/glew.h>` was missing on a file, now it works using `glew`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[glEnableVertexAttribArray](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glEnableVertexAttribArray)  and [glVertexAttribPointer](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttribPointer) are "modern" replacement for glEnableClientState/glVertexPointer. The new generic variant has been available since GL 2.0.

Comment: Oh, I was assuming that the code examples I had were from version 3. I need to use this method because it is home assignment and they require us to write OpenGL using it. Thank you, I have edited the question.